# Looping through $_POST variables

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry i could not find a proper title to this question.
I have generated the following using a for loop and I have concatenated the names of the submits buttons using the pattern below:
submit_edit_category_1
submit_edit_category_2
submit_edit_category_3

```
echo "<input type='submit' value = 'Edit' name='submit_edit_category_" . 
$obj_categories_admin->categories[$i]['category_id'] . "'/>";
```

I want to loop through these values so that I can the button action whichis edit_category and the category id which is 1,2 or 3. I want to so something like:

```
if(isset($_POST) == 'edit_category'))
{
    //code here
}
```

Someone suggested me to do it this way:

```
name="submit[which_action][which_category]"  
a1 = $_POST['submit']; 
$which_action = reset(array_keys($a1)); 
$which_category = reset(array_keys($a1[$which_action]));
```

This does not seem to work..Can anyone give me a different way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

here what I'd do:

for the actual form, I'd use array keys to communicate action and relevant id info.

```
$cat_id =  $obj_categories_admin->categories[$i]['category_id'];

echo "<input type='submit' value = 'Edit' name='submit[edit_category][" . $cat_id . "]'/>";
```

then when posted, I can do:

```
<?php

list($action, $action_params) = each($_POST['submit']);
list($cat_id, $button_label) = each($action_params);

print_r($_POST['submit']); // prints array('edit_category' => array('1' => 'Edit'))
echo($action); //prints "edit_category"
print_r($action_params); //prints array('1' => 'Edit')
echo($cat_id); //prints "1"
echo($button_label); //prints "Edit"
```

edit: for more info on each(), go here: https://www.php.net/each . I've personally always felt that 's lack of differentation between the button label and the it's value to be frustrating. Using an array key to stuff info into the button has always been my favorite hack.

Answer (score 26):

**UPD:** Please, use Mike's advice. It's much better to have more structured data in POST.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
  if(strpos($key, 'submit_edit_category_') === 0 ) {
    print $key.' => '.$val.'\r\n';
    print substr($key, 21 /* or 22... or 23... try yourself */ );
  }
}
```

Comment: As I see here, my answer has better rating than Mike's. But it's not fair :) Mike shows true way to do it. Your POST data should be more structured and if your data is the array, it should be an array in the POST too.

Comment: @Adelf Would be better to add it in the beginning of your post

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
foreach ($_POST AS $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'submit_edit_category_') !== false) {
        $catID = (int)str_replace('submit_edit_category_', '', $key);
        echo 'Category ID: ' . $catID . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the way you build the name to this:

`submit__edit_category__1`

Then, try this:

```
function filter_by_submit($var)
{
    return stripos($var, "submit") !== false ? true : false;
}

$submits = array_filter(array_keys($_POST), "filter_by_submit");
foreach ($submits as $sub)
{
    if ($_POST[$sub] == "Edit")
    {
        list($submit, $action, $id) = explode("__", $sub);  
        break;
    }
}
```

`$submit` will hold the string `"submit"`. `$action` will hold `"edit_category"` and `$id` will hold the id of the pressed button. The pressed button is determined by matching its value to the tag's value (i.e., when **submit__edit_category__1** is pressed, the value  `"Edit"` is POSTed).

Comment: What if I have other buttons such as Edit Details and Delete apart from Edit?

Comment: You can use a switch {...} instead of an if to match the action and the value.