# Submit multiple data inside a foreach loop

Tags: php

I  have a code that displays all the values that are checked from a list of checkboxes like this:

```
$query = "SELECT products_name, categories_desc, id, price
    FROM products, categories
    WHERE products.categories_id = categories.categories_id";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$last_category='';
echo "<table>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if ($last_category!=$row['categories_desc']){
    echo "<tr><td><b>" . $row['categories_desc'] . "</b></td></tr>";
    $last_category=$row['categories_desc'];
}

echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='shekbaks[]' name='shekbaks[]' value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" .
    $row['products_name'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>-</td><td>P" . $row['price'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Then, after the user has checked the boxes and submit it, I associate a number for it using a textbox so that they can specify the quantity they need and it looks like this:

```
if( isset($_POST['shekbaks']) && is_array($_POST['shekbaks']) ) {
    echo "<form action='' method='post'><table>";

    foreach($_POST['shekbaks'] as $shekbaks) {

        //DISPLAY
        $query2 = "SELECT id, products_name, price FROM products WHERE id='" . $shekbaks . "'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
        while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
            echo "&nbsp&nbsp<small><b>" . $row2['products_name'] .
            "<br> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - x</b>
            <input type='hidden' name='prods' value='" . $row2['id'] . "'>
            <input type='number' name='quant' style='width:30px;' min='1' value='1'></small><br>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table><input type='submit' name='submitOrder'></form>";
}
```

I would like to submit them in the table `orders` with the fields

- products_id
- quantity

but am having troubles doing so. I put the `prods` thinking that it could help ease the insertion knowing both the datas are in input types. Sadly, I still have no idea how to insert them.

Help anyone? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I understand, you're making a `POST` request to this `php` script to query the products from a database and display them in a form for the user to select. There are two options you have to insert data from the form from this script. If you don't want to lose context of this script. Make a simple `POST` request using [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or pure javascript for that matter. Or specify a separate target in the `action` attribute for that form and in that script write the necessary code to insert the selected values.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123, yes that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @VivekPradhan, I am having problems gathering the data because it is in a foreach loop and the closest try I have made resulted to only the first data being inserted, and I couldn't repeat that trial anymore.

Comment: Ok, I think I now understand your problem. One thing that you can do for easy reference of the product name and quantity is prefix the `name` tag of both your inputs in the form with `$row2['products_name']`. In that way for every product, the input names will be sort of uniquely identified. And just store all the `$row2['products_name']` in a separate array may be. While inserting into the database. Just iterate the array and pick the corresponding values from the `input` elements.

Comment: Okay, I've updated it. Thank you.

Comment: @VivekPradhan, I'm sorry but I'm really new in PHP and I can't put the idea into one place. I understand the logic, but I have no idea how to put them into codes. :(

Answer (score 0):

You probabily want to use input element as arrays. Use product id as array key

```
<input type='number' name='quant[X]' style='width:30px;' min='1' value='1'>
```

Where X is product id, ie, `$row2['id']`

And after form submit you can use input array quant where key of the array element is product id and value is quantity.

```
foreach($_POST['quant'] as $product_id => $quantity) {
    // process here
}
```

Comment: Err.. Should I do it like.. `$x = $row2['id']`? Sorry, I'm really having troubles here.

Comment: Use single input field. hidden field not needed, `echo "<input type='number' name='quant[".$row2['id']."]' style='width:30px;' min='1' value='1'>";`

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna give you a starting point on how to go about it. For example, here I'm assuming that once the user has checked on the products he wants to order and redirected to that form where he is supposed to select the quantity, the form is submitted to some `foo.php` script that takes care of the insertion part into the database (just to keep the code clean).

Your current code could look something like:

```
if( isset($_POST['shekbaks']) && is_array($_POST['shekbaks']) ) {
echo "<form action='foo.php' method='post'><table>";

//I'm defining an empty array to just store the checked product names for easy retrieval
$productnames=array();
foreach($_POST['shekbaks'] as $shekbaks) {

    //DISPLAY
    $query2 = "SELECT id, products_name, price FROM products WHERE id='" . $shekbaks . "'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    while ($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

        //Push the product name into the defined arrray
        array_push($productnames,$row2['products_name']);

        //Display info for the specific product
        //Store the quantity of the prodcut with the input name set as product name
        //This makes it unique and would help in retrieving it easily

        echo "&nbsp&nbsp<small><b>" . $row2['products_name'] .
        "<br> - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - x</b>

        <input type='number' name='".$row2['products_name']."' style='width:30px;' min='1' value='1'></small><br>";
    }
}
$arr = serialize($productnames); //Serialize the array to pass it along with the form as an input
echo "</table><input type='hidden' name='productnames' value='$arr' />
<input type='submit' name='submitOrder'></form>";
}
```

Now once this form is submitted. The data is sent to `foo.php` using a `POST` request. The `foo.php` could look something like:

```
$productnames = unserialize($_POST["productnames"]); //Get the array of product names
foreach ($productnames as $value) {
  //Here you can get the respective product name and associated quantity
  echo $value; //Product name
  echo $_POST[$value]; //Gives you the quantity as we chose the input names accordingly

 //Here you can insert the two values in orders table
}
```

There are of course more efficient ways of doing it. Extra space is consumed here as we pass an explicit array along with the form. You could also use [array keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263128/looping-through-post-variables) right inside the input names and I suggest you give that a try yourself.

I did it just so that you can get an idea of how you should proceed with the problem. This should get you started in the right direction.